# Modifying Pycharm's Jupyter Notebook Preview

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I would like to modify the preview appearance of markdown in a Jupyter Notebook running in Pycharm: things like line separation, colors, font size, etc. However, even if I go to "Add CSS rules" in the Languages & Frameworks settings, it will not take effect after apply (at least not in the Jupyter Markdown), it does in plain Markdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Updated Jupyter Notebook support is young and hence lacks some features, feel free to open an issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY